# Removing Wiper Arm from Chevy Suburban?

Tags: chevrolet, replace, windshield-wipers

I have a Chevrolet Suburban, 1500 model, year 2001. 
How do I remove the wiper arm of my Chevy after I remove the base cap and nut.
The arm is not coming off the base after significant prying with screw driver.

On image the base of wiper arm is on the left, wiper extends to the right.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPnMU.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to use a Windshield Wiper Arm Puller (shown below). These are about $15usd and most likely available at any auto store. But, before going and spending money, spray the threaded area with some WD-40 and let it sit for a few minutes, this will give it time to set in. Next, place the wiper in the *service* position* as if you were about to replace the wiper blades *(this will require you to lower the hood)*. Once in position, place one hand where the wiper arm makes a 90 degree angle. Then rock it back and forth and it will hopefully wiggle free.

- Windshield Wiper Arm Puller

  [image: wiperarmpuller]

Answer (score 2):

The wiper arm is on a tapered shaft, so it won't release easily.  I did some grinding/modifying on a puller I had on hand and was able to get the arm loose. I checked two parts houses for the arm puller and they were not even aware that the puller existed. There is also no keyway to help install the new arm in the correct position.  Best to put the wipers in the rest position, then adjust so the blades are just above the bottom of the windshield.  If you do one arm at a time it may be easier.  The puller shown in the above answer will work well, if you can find one.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair!

Answer (score 1):

When my 2002 silversdo was new the arm slipped several times. The dealer Loctited them in place. Try using a small gearpuller. If you don't have a small puller try a battery terminal puller. If you can't grab the arm with a puller you may need a wiperarm removal tool. It is a small lever that prys on the arm without damage to the plastic trim.